# Model.findById() in Mongoose - Async/await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, async-await

The [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) say that the function findById() returns a Query.

In that doc you can see an example where we can use async/await in this way:

```
await Adventure.findById(id, 'name length').exec();
```

How is that possible that we can use async/await for a function that does not return a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer.

findById() returns a Query.

The type Query has a function called [exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec). That is the function that actually returns the promise.

That is why we can use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

From the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) we have:

Mongoose async operations, like .save() and queries, return thenables. This means that you can do things like MyModel.findOne({}).then() and await MyModel.findOne({}).exec() if you're using async/await.

You can find the return type of specific operations in the api docs You can also read more about promises in Mongoose.

And actually Model.findById() calls Model.findOne as the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) says:

This function triggers the following middleware.

- findOne()